# How to do an efficient boolean "false or undefined" query in Parse?

Tags: parse-platform

I have a `Boolean` column on one of my Parse entities, and I want to query for all rows that have this column either explicitly set to `false`, or left to its default `undefined` value.

I can't do `equalTo('myBoolColumn', false)`, because it doesn't return rows that have an `undefined` value for this column.

I'd rather not do a `notEqualTo('myBoolColumn', true)`, because the [Parse documentation](https://www.parse.com/docs/js/guide#performance-not-equal-to) states that `notEqualTo` queries are not efficient because they can't take advantage of indexes.

The documentation suggests using `containedIn` instead, but it feels wrong to write a `containedIn('myBoolColumn', [false, undefined])` query to achieve the expected result.

It seems like `notEqualTo` boolean queries could still be indexed, but I did not find an authoritative source that confirms this, and I don't know how to test if this query uses an index or not.

So which one should I use: `notEqualTo('myBoolColumn', true)` or `containedIn('myBoolColumn', [false, undefined])`?

Comment: What's wrong with an if/else condition. If true do something, else it's false or undefined

Comment: I'm writing a query, not code.

Comment: Yes. You write a query for one specific parameter (equalTo('', true)). And if it doesn't match that parameter, naturally it's the false,undefined objects

Comment: But I need to fetch those [false/undefined] objects. If I query for `equalTo(true)`, I'm not going to get them at all...

Comment: Right. I don't think I'm explaining right. I'll share an answer when I get home from work, provided the one below isn't sufficient

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want to combine two queries like so:

```js
var falseQuery = new Parse.Query('YourClass');
falseQuery.equalTo('myBoolColumn', false);

var undefinedQuery = new Parse.Query('YourClass');
undefinedQuery.doesNotExist('myBoolColumn');

//this is the query you should run
var query = Parse.Query.or(falseQuery, undefinedQuery);
query.find({....});
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this a try and keep an eye on the _Slow Queries_ analytics page in my Parse console.

Comment: Would you mind marking as correct? This is the Parse way of doing this correctly. Would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're checking for whether it's false or undefined, you could also more simply do:

```
var query = new Parse.Query('YourClass');
query.notEqualTo('myBoolColumn', true);

query.find({...});
```

Comment: Thanks, but I had explicitly stated that I'd rather not do a `notEqualTo` in my question.

Comment: @PascalBourque got excited, my bad :)