# Querying a Boolean column returns empty list

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am trying to query a Boolean column "isFeatured" having true/false values in the  "Business" table as follow, but the result is always an empty list:

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<>("Business");
query.include("tags");
query.whereNear("locationCoordinates", parseGeoPoint);
query.whereEqualTo("isFeatured","true");
```

Not sure what i am doing wrong over here. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: can you try `query.whereEqualTo("isFeatured",true); // true(boolean)` ?

Comment: tried with  true, "true", "YES", "1" , non works

Comment: just turned out that the  "locationCoordinates" was the culprit, and query.whereEqualTo("isFeatured",true); helped , the entries having invalid or null location details was causing the empty results

Comment: see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32187220/how-to-do-an-efficient-boolean-false-or-undefined-query-in-parse) may solve your problem with multiple query.

Comment: Brilliant, it seems a really good way to go, will update here after testing

Comment: It works but only fro that queries which are not geoQueries  such as query.whereNear("locationCoordinates", parseGeoPoint);

Comment: can you add new code in your question for get more idea!